# How to iterate by an elemental index loop rather than char by char when iterating through a file

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file) {

        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (c != 'a') {
                putchar(c);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Basically, the program just takes in a file as stdin, then removes every a and prints to stdout. For example

```
$ gcc -Wall removeA.c
$ echo 123a >file1
$ ./a.out file1
123
```

My question is, how can I make the code go by it's index position and also get the length of it rather than go by char by char. Something like below (It doesn't work)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int i = 0;
    if (file) {

        while (i < len) {
            if (c[i] != 'a') {
                putchar(c[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Other than a memory-mapped file?

Comment: Was trying to give an example of how I want it to go index by index

Comment: Obviously you're going to have to read the file into a buffer first to do that. Determine the file length (various techniques), then malloc() a buffer that large, read the whole file in, and you're good to go. If it's a long-lived application, of course you'd also need to free() the buffer when done. Or as @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams mentions, map the file into memory is another way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could use `fread` to read the file block-by-block into a buffer (length of buffer would be your choice) and index the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `fgets`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
   char buffer[BUFSIZ];
   FILE *file;
   file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (file)
   {
      // Read BUFSIZ-1 number of characters at a time.
      while ( fgets(buffer, BUFSIZ, file) != NULL )
      {
         for ( size_t i = 0;  buffer[i] != '\0'; ++i )
         {
            char c = buffer[i];
            if (c != 'a')
            {
               putchar(c);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If the file contains binary data, you can use `fread` instead of `fgets`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
   char buffer[BUFSIZ];
   FILE *file;
   file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
   if (file)
   {
      // Read BUFSIZ number of characters at a time.
      size_t n = 0;
      while ( (n = fread(buffer, 1, BUFSIZ, file)) > 0 )
      {
         for ( size_t i = 0;  i < n; ++i )
         {
            char c = buffer[i];
            if (c != 'a')
            {
               putchar(c);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started....

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fp)
{
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  size_t flen = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  char *fbuf = (char*)malloc(flen + 1); // +1 to add a nul-term at the end
  if (!fbuf)
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory trying to read file\n");
     exit(1);
  }
  if (fread(fbuf, 1, flen, fp) != flen) // read the whole file at once
  {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file\n");
     exit(1);
  }
  fbuf[flen] = '\0'; // nul-term the buffer in case you use "str" functions on it
  fclose(fp);
  ...
```